# Undefined control sequence with \autocite and biblatex-chicago.sty

Tags: biblatex, errors, pandoc, biblatex-chicago, undefined

I get an 'Undefined control sequence \autocite{donnellanSpeakingNothing1974}' error with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{donnellanSpeakingNothing1974}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and bibliography.bib:

```
@Article{donnellanSpeakingNothing1974,
  author       = {Donnellan, Keith S.},
  title        = {Speaking of Nothing},
  journaltitle = {The Philosophical Review},
  date         = {1974},
  volume       = {83},
  number       = {1},
  pages        = {3--31},
  doi          = {10.2307/2183871},
}
```

This is not a duplicate of ["Undefined control sequence." when using autocite and biblatex-chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365157/undefined-control-sequence-when-using-autocite-and-biblatex-chicago) because I am not using bibtex.

What do I need to do to use `\autocite` with [biblatex-chicago](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago)?

I want to use autocite, because I want to make the .tex file with [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) and that's how it writes citations.

I am passing a style option to biblatex.sty because that's how Pandoc's templates work. This may be the source of my problems: [Difference between biblatex [style=chicago] and biblatex-chicago packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59222/difference-between-biblatex-style-chicago-and-biblatex-chicago-packages)

According to page 87 of the biblatex-chicago manual I should use xstring.sty and nameref.sty. That doesn't help; the following gives me the same error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{donnellanSpeakingNothing1974}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles from the `biblatex-chicago` bundle are supposed to be loaded via the wrapper package `biblatex-chicago`. This is a quirk of that particular style bundle, but it is established by now.

You cannot expect to get the same result as

```
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
```

from `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}`.

Amongst other things the wrapper package sets a lot of package loading options for the style you selected. The following should be pretty close to what `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` would give you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  pagetracker=true,autocite=inline,alldates=comp,labeldateparts=true,
  citetracker=true,uniquename=minfull,useeditor=true,usetranslator=true,
  usenamec=true,alltimes=12h,urltime=24h,datecirca=true,datezeros=false,
  dateuncertain=true,timezones=true,compressyears=true,
  ibidtracker=constrict,sorting=cms,punctfont,cmslos=true,nodates,
  uniquelist=minyear,maxbibnames=10,minbibnames=7,sortcase=false,
  abbreviate=false,dateabbrev=false,avdate=true}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

or if you prefer to pass the options directly to `biblatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,
  pagetracker=true,autocite=inline,alldates=comp,labeldateparts=true,
  citetracker=true,uniquename=minfull,useeditor=true,usetranslator=true,
  usenamec=true,alltimes=12h,urltime=24h,datecirca=true,datezeros=false,
  dateuncertain=true,timezones=true,compressyears=true,
  ibidtracker=constrict,sorting=cms,punctfont,cmslos=true,nodates,
  uniquelist=minyear,maxbibnames=10,minbibnames=7,sortcase=false,
  abbreviate=false,dateabbrev=false,avdate=true,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The immediate error about `\autocite` can also be removed with the shorter

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate, autocite=inline,]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

but then other parts of the style may not be as intended by the style author (and required by the CMS).

Note that even the two long option invocations don't do everything `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` does. If you are interested in that you can copy everything after (and not including) `\expandafter\ExecuteBibliographyOptions\expandafter{\cms@options}` up to (and again not including) `\endiput` from [`biblatex-chicago.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/latex/biblatex-chicago.sty) into your preamble between `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

Seems the `\autocite` is the problem. Got it to work, though:

Try this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xstring, nameref}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@Article{donnellanSpeakingNothing1974,
  author       = {Donnellan, Keith S.},
  title        = {Speaking of Nothing},
  journaltitle = {The Philosophical Review},
  date         = {1974},
  volume       = {83},
  number       = {1},
  pages        = {3--31},
  doi          = {10.2307/2183871},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}

This is a citing test \autocite{donnellanSpeakingNothing1974}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Forgot the output:

[image: Autocite inline]

Comment: According to page 3 of the biblatex-chicago manual, the option 'chicago-authordate' exists. I don't get an error about that, as I would if I used 'style=foo'.

Comment: The alternative you give works, but I can't do it that way because I have to pass options to biblatex.sty.

Comment: `style=chicago-authordate` exists.https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59222/91556

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me that loading `biblatex-chicago` has become mandatory. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @phil-elkabat The manual for biblatex-chicago says that it is recommended, not mandatory (page 87).

Comment: I wouldn't need 'style=chicago-authordate' if I was calling biblatex-chicago.sty. I could use 'authordate' as in the first version of this answer.

Comment: @twsh, Got it to work, see the newest edit.

Comment: @phil-elkabat That works, but it's still calling biblatex-chicago.sty. I want to make it work by passing options to biblatex.sty because that's what pandoc will do. But maybe that's not possible.

Comment: @twsh, yeah sorry. I should probably call it a day. I think it works now. What i did was to add `autocite=inline` as an option. Could you try it and let me know?

Comment: That works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up using `\citet{}` and `\citep{}`...